# single = on while loop

Tags: php, operators, while-loop

i'm practicing php at nowadays. i have one question.

i see one **`=`** on some while loops. often on mysql queries. so what does it stands for?

two **`==`** means equal. but single **`=`** ? can you tell me the logic behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

This keeps querying the result handle until a `NULL` value (end of result) is found. `$row` then contains the row fetched from the call so it can be used for processing.

It is also "shorthand" for checking for a `NULL` result:

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) != null)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

It can also replace a `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($query); $i++)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

All are equivalent.

Answer (score 11):

Single `=` means "assignment". An assignment always assigns to a variable and returns the result. So, for example:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    // ...
}
```

While `mysql_fetch_array($results)` returns a valid array, it loops. When it returns `null` (meaning that's the end of the results) the loop exits.

Comment: I think your answer would benefit if you explain that the assignment is part of the expression, e.g. that $row will contain the result of mysl_fetch_array() and while tests that exact same result as well.

Comment: Well, so you have a MySQL result set. `mysql_fetch_array` takes the *next* result in that set and returns it, or `null` if there are no more records. So a `while` loop loops through all the returned records, putting each one into `$row` each time.

Comment: @jankli: The point is to do two things at once: assign a value to $row "while" testing that value in the while loop (as test to continue the loop).

Answer (score 2):

single = is for assignment

```
$a = 9;
```

== is for comparison

```
if($a == 9) echo 'hello';
```

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_operators.asp

Comment: it assigns a row from the DB result set to the $row var, it would continue to loop while there is a row to be assigned, otherwise the loop will end. Now inside the loop you can use $row var to utilize the row data, like $row['col_1'].

Answer (score 1):

That's the **assignment** operator.

Answer (score 0):

While the current value of 'x' can be successfully assigned to variable 'y', continue on.

Comment: Not quite.  It's more like 'assign x to y, and test if y is true'

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($thing);
while (isset($row)) {

  // do stuff

  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($thing);
}
```

You can see that it's a bit less typing (and the code is probably more efficient) here:

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($thing)) != null) {
  // do stuff
}
```